# ActionView::Template::Error (Undefined method new_contract_months_path for ) after remove model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I got this error when I tried to create a simple form in rails 3. My `_new_contract_month.html.erb` is:

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Contract') %>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <%= form_for NewContractMonth.new, url: new_contract_month_path do |f| %>
                <%= f.label :serial_number, "Serial Number", :size => 60 %>
                <%= f.text_field :serial_number %>
                <%= f.label :sale, "Sele", :size => 60 %>
                <%= f.text_field :sale %>
                <%= f.label :goal_profit, "Goal profit rate", :size => 60%>
                <%= f.text_field :goal_profit %>
                <%= f.label :alert_mail, "Alert Mail" %>
                <%= f.check_box :alert_mail %>
                <%= f.label "Date" %>
                <%= f.select :date, NewContractMonth::DATE.collect {|s| [l("date_#{s}"), s]}%>
                <%= f.label "Start Date"%>
                <%= f.text_field :start_date, :size => 10 %><%= calendar_for('new_contract_month_start_date') %>
                <%= f.label "End Date"%>
                <%= f.text_field :end_date, :size => 10 %><%= calendar_for('new_contract_month_end_date') %>
                <%= f.label "Description", :size => 100%>
                <%= f.textfield :description%>
                <%= f.label "Status"%>
                <%= f.select :status, NewContractMonth::STATUS.collect {|f| [l("status_#{f}"), f]}%>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.summit "Save"%>
    </div>
</div>
```

my `route.rb` is:

```
# Plugin's routes
# See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
if Rails.version.to_f >= 3.0
  match 'attendance_time_money/index/:id', :to => 'attendance_time_money#index', :via => :get
  match 'analysis_time_money/index/:id', :to => 'analysis_time_money#index', :via => :get
  match 'setting_time_money/index/:id', :to => 'setting_time_money#index', :via => :get
  match 'setting_time_money/new/:id' , :to => 'setting_time_money#new', :via => :get
  match 'setting_time_money/new_contract_month/:id' , :to => 'setting_time_money#new_contract_month', :via => :get


else # Routes for older Rails routes
  ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
   map.connect '/attendance_time_money/index/:id', :controller => 'attendance_time_money', :action => 'index'
   map.connect '/analysis_time_money/index/:id', :controller => 'analysis_time_money', :action => 'index'
   map.connect '/setting_time_money/index/:id', :controller => 'setting_time_money', :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

my controller:

```
class SettingTimeMoneyController < ApplicationController
  unloadable


  def index
    @new_contract_month = NewContractMonth.all
    @new_contract_version = NewContractMonth.all
  end

  def new_contract_month
    @new_contract_month ||= NewContractMonth.new
    @new_contract_version ||= NewContractVersion.new
  end

  def edit_contract
    @new_contract_month = NewContractMonth.find(params[:id])
    @new_contract_version = NewContractMonth.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update_contract
    respond_to do |format|
      if @new_contract.update(new_contract_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @new_contract, notice: 'New contract was successfully updated'}
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render 'new_contract'}
        format.json { render json: @new_contract.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
     end
  end


end
```

I searched google and find a solution to fix this problem by add `:as => new_contract_month` to route file. Unfortunately, after that, I delete my `new_contract_month.rb` model and then add it again(the same name, with more attributes). When I run my app again, the error comeback and I get stuck until now. So can someone help me?
This is log after I run `rake routes`:

```
 projects#update
                                       DELETE       /projects                                attachments#show
                                       DELETE       
                      admin_test_email GET          /admin/test_email(.:format)                                                       admin#test_email
           admin_default_configuration POST         /admin/default_configuration(.:format)                                            admin#default_configuration
            try_connection_auth_source GET          /auth_sources/:id/test_connection(.:format)                                       auth_sources#test_connection
autocomplete_for_new_user_auth_sources GET          /auth_sources/autocomplete_for_new_user(.:format)                                 auth_sources#autocomplete_for_new_user
                          auth_sources GET          /auth_sources(.:format)                                                           auth_sources#index
                                       POST         /auth_sources(.:format)                                                           auth_sources#create
                       new_auth_source GET          /auth_sources/new(.:format)                                                       auth_sources#new
                      edit_auth_source GET          /auth_sources/:id/edit(.:format)                                                  auth_sources#edit
                           auth_source GET          /auth_sources/:id(.:format)                                                       auth_sources#show
                                       PUT          /auth_sources/:id(.:format)                                                       auth_sources#update
                                       DELETE       /auth_sources/:id(.:format)                                                       auth_sources#destroy
                             workflows GET          /workflows(.:format)                                                              workflows#index
                        workflows_edit GET|POST     /workflows/edit(.:format)                                                         workflows#edit
                 workflows_permissions GET|POST     /workflows/permissions(.:format)                                                  workflows#permissions
                        workflows_copy GET|POST     /workflows/copy(.:format)                                                         workflows#copy
                              settings GET          /settings(.:format)                                                               settings#index
                         settings_edit GET|POST     /settings/edit(.:format)                                                          settings#edit
                       plugin_settings GET|POST     /settings/plugin/:id(.:format)                                                    settings#plugin
                          sys_projects GET          /sys/projects(.:format)                                                           sys#projects
                                       POST         /sys/projects/:id/repository(.:format)                                            sys#create_project_repository
                  sys_fetch_changesets GET          /sys/fetch_changesets(.:format)                                                   sys#fetch_changesets
                               uploads POST         /uploads(.:format)                                                                attachments#upload
                                       GET          /robots.txt(.:format)                                                             welcome#robots
                                                    /work_time/:action(.:format)                                                      work_time#index
                                                    /work_time/:action/:id(.:format)                                                  work_time#show
                     view_issues_count GET          /view_issues_count(.:format)                                                      issue_count#index
                      view_login_count GET          /view_login_count(.:format)                                                       login_count#index
             view_redmine_issues_count GET          /view_redmine_issues_count(.:format)                                              redmine_issues_count#index
                                       GET          /work_life_balance/index/:id(.:format)                                            work_life_balance#index
                                       GET          /attendance_time_money/index/:id(.:format)                                        attendance_time_money#index
                                       GET          /analysis_time_money/index/:id(.:format)                                          analysis_time_money#index
                                       GET          /setting_time_money/index/:id(.:format)                                           setting_time_money#index
                                       GET          /setting_time_money/new/:id(.:format)                                             setting_time_money#new
                        contract_month              /setting_time_money/new_contract_month/:id(.:format)                              setting_time_money#new_contract_month
                                       GET          /attendance_time_money/index/:id(.:format)                                        attendance_time_money#index
                                       GET          /analysis_time_money/index/:id(.:format)                                          analysis_time_money#index
                                       GET          /setting_time_money/index/:id(.:format)                                           setting_time_money#index
                                       GET          /setting_time_money/new/:id(.:format)                                             setting_time_money#new
                    new_contract_month              /setting_time_money/new_contract_month/:id(.:format)                              setting_time_money#new_contract_month
                                       GET          /secretary/day.:format                                                            secretary#day
                                       GET          /secretary/interval.:format                                                       secretary#interval
   manage_special_day_pocket_calendars PUT          /pocket_calendars/manage_special_day(.:format)                                    pocket_calendars#manage_special_day
         change_month_pocket_calendars PUT          /pocket_calendars/change_month(.:format)                                          pocket_calendars#change_month
                      pocket_calendars GET          /pocket_calendars(.:format)                                                       pocket_calendars#index
                                       POST         /pocket_calendars(.:format)                                                       pocket_calendars#create
                   new_pocket_calendar GET          /pocket_calendars/new(.:format)                                                   pocket_calendars#new
                  edit_pocket_calendar GET          /pocket_calendars/:id/edit(.:format)                                              pocket_calendars#edit
                       pocket_calendar GET          /pocket_calendars/:id(.:format)                                                   pocket_calendars#show
                                       PUT          /pocket_calendars/:id(.:format)                                                   pocket_calendars#update
                                       DELETE       /pocket_calendars/:id(.:format)                                                   pocket_calendars#destroy
                             day_types GET          /day_types(.:format)                                                              day_types#index
                                       POST         /day_types(.:format)                                                              day_types#create
                          new_day_type GET          /day_types/new(.:format)                                                          day_types#new
                         edit_day_type GET          /day_types/:id/edit(.:format)                                                     day_types#edit
                              day_type GET          /day_types/:id(.:format)                                                          day_types#show
                                       PUT          /day_types/:id(.:format)                                                          day_types#update
                                       DELETE       /day_types/:id(.:format)                                                          day_types#destroy
                         week_patterns GET          /week_patterns(.:format)                                                          week_patterns#index
                                       POST         /week_patterns(.:format)                                                          week_patterns#create
                      new_week_pattern GET          /week_patterns/new(.:format)                                                      week_patterns#new
                     edit_week_pattern GET          /week_patterns/:id/edit(.:format)                                                 week_patterns#edit
                          week_pattern GET          /week_patterns/:id(.:format)                                                      week_patterns#show
                                       PUT          /week_patterns/:id(.:format)                                                      week_patterns#update
                                       DELETE       /week_patterns/:id(.:format)                                                      week_patterns#destroy
                                       GET          /home_monitoring_controlling_project/index/:id(.:format)                          home_monitoring_controlling_project#index
                                       GET          /mc_time_mgmt_project/index/:id(.:format)                                         mc_time_mgmt_project#index
                                       GET          /mc_human_resource_project/index/:id(.:format)                                    mc_human_resource_mgmt_project#index
             project_pivot_table_index GET          /projects/:project_id/pivot_table(.:format)                                       pivot_table#index
                 project_pivot_queries POST         /projects/:project_id/pivot_queries(.:format)                                     pivot_queries#create
               new_project_pivot_query GET          /projects/:project_id/pivot_queries/new(.:format)                                 pivot_queries#new
                project_custom_queries POST         /projects/:project_id/custom_queries(.:format)                                    custom_queries#create
              new_project_custom_query GET          /projects/:project_id/custom_queries/new(.:format)                                custom_queries#new
         project_pivot_dashboard_index POST         /projects/:project_id/pivot_dashboard(.:format)                                   pivot_dashboard#create
           new_project_pivot_dashboard GET          /projects/:project_id/pivot_dashboard/new(.:format)                               pivot_dashboard#new
          project_show_dashboard_index GET          /projects/:project_id/show_dashboard(.:format)                                    show_dashboard#index
       project_pivot_table_chart_index POST         /projects/:project_id/pivot_table_chart(.:format)                                 pivot_table_chart#create
         new_project_pivot_table_chart GET          /projects/:project_id/pivot_table_chart/new(.:format)                             pivot_table_chart#new
                                       GET          /projects(.:format)                                                               projects#index
                                       POST         /projects(.:format)                                                               projects#create
                                       GET          /projects/new(.:format)                                                           projects#new
                                       GET          /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                                                      projects#edit
                                       GET          /projects/:id(.:format)                                                           projects#show
                                       PUT          /projects/:id(.:format)                                                           projects#update
                                       DELETE       /projects/:id(.:format)                                                           projects#destroy
                     pivot_table_index GET          /pivot_table(.:format)                                                            pivot_table#index
                         pivot_queries GET          /pivot_queries(.:format)                                                          pivot_queries#index
                                       POST         /pivot_queries(.:format)                                                          pivot_queries#create
                       new_pivot_query GET          /pivot_queries/new(.:format)                                                      pivot_queries#new
                      edit_pivot_query GET          /pivot_queries/:id/edit(.:format)                                                 pivot_queries#edit
                           pivot_query PUT          /pivot_queries/:id(.:format)                                                      pivot_queries#update
                                       DELETE       /pivot_queries/:id(.:format)                                                      pivot_queries#destroy
                        custom_queries GET          /custom_queries(.:format)                                                         custom_queries#index
                                       POST         /custom_queries(.:format)                                                         custom_queries#create
                      new_custom_query GET          /custom_queries/new(.:format)                                                     custom_queries#new
                     edit_custom_query GET          /custom_queries/:id/edit(.:format)                                                custom_queries#edit
                          custom_query PUT          /custom_queries/:id(.:format)                                                     custom_queries#update
                                       DELETE       /custom_queries/:id(.:format)                                                     custom_queries#destroy
               pivot_table_chart_index GET          /pivot_table_chart(.:format)                                                      pivot_table_chart#index
                                       POST         /pivot_table_chart(.:format)                                                      pivot_table_chart#create
                 new_pivot_table_chart GET          /pivot_table_chart/new(.:format)                                                  pivot_table_chart#new
                edit_pivot_table_chart GET          /pivot_table_chart/:id/edit(.:format)                                             pivot_table_chart#edit
                     pivot_table_chart PUT          /pivot_table_chart/:id(.:format)                                                  pivot_table_chart#update
                                       DELETE       /pivot_table_chart/:id(.:format)                                                  pivot_table_chart#destroy
                 pivot_dashboard_index GET          /pivot_dashboard(.:format)                                                        pivot_dashboard#index
                                       POST         /pivot_dashboard(.:format)                                                        pivot_dashboard#create
                   new_pivot_dashboard GET          /pivot_dashboard/new(.:format)                                                    pivot_dashboard#new
                  edit_pivot_dashboard GET          /pivot_dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)                                               pivot_dashboard#edit
                       pivot_dashboard PUT          /pivot_dashboard/:id(.:format)                                                    pivot_dashboard#update
                                       DELETE       /pivot_dashboard/:id(.:format)                                                    pivot_dashboard#destroy
                  show_dashboard_index GET          /show_dashboard(.:format)                                                         show_dashboard#index
```

Comment: Could you run `rake routes` in console in root of your project, and paste what has been displayed please? It would give us some hint where we should head with this problem.

Comment: And one more thing - where is exactly the error about missing `new_contract_months_path` coming from? From your `routes` it looks like, you should use `new_contract_month_path` instead (its subtle difference, but the error says about missing method for *plural* **months**, when you have defined *singular* **month** in your config)